# Ubuntu - why are all new directories I create owned by root?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

Recently I noticed that new directories I create are always owned by root. Is this how supposed to be? I created this directory to put html files for a web server `/var/www/site1/html/index.html` and it is owned by root. I did `sudo chown -R a:a /path-to-directory` to change the owner to me; and I did `sudo chmod 777 -R /path-to-directory` to change permissions for all. Now I have:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 a a 2 Dec 17 19:18 index.html
```

How can I create directories so that I own the directories I created with read and write permissions? And is it good to change a file read/write/execute for all?

Comment: If you are setting up a public webserver, you should probably make a user account dedicated to that purpose and have the files for it owned by that user. Typically, anyway - for home server use, probably not an issue.

Comment: chmod 777 is the second worst pitfall after the abuse of using a root shell, please don't use it unless you are very sure why do you want that

Comment: not the droids, not the answer for the question asked by @Zeynel, BUT another answer to this exact question that I don't see elsewhere on superuser.com is "On a system without entry for the user in /etc/passwd. When the user creates file or directory the owner is root."

Answer (score 5):

Ownership should be dictated by who is creating the directory. If your user does the `mkdir` command, it should have ownership of the directory.

However, if you use `sudo mkdir` then the `root` is the user actually creating the directory, not your user. If your user does not have permissions in the parent directory to create the subdirectory, which is the only reason to use `sudo mkdir` then the best way to resolve this is to change the directory permissions for the parent directory.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In `/etc/nginx/site1.conf` I assume that it is not good to change the ownership of `/etc/` (because it is system file?) but I went ahead and changed `/nginx/` and sub directories to user and now I can edit it in emacs. What is the best practice to changing/not changing permissions of directories?

Comment: Depends on what you are worried about, exactly. If you're worried about rogue users being able to see the directory using some kind of directory mapping through html you could always change the permissions using sudo on the parent directory, then change them back to the safe octal after you're done making your adjustments. Once you've created the directory if you don't -R the chmod it won't affect them, just the parent. Real discussion of permissions best practices is probably best for a separate question though, after some google fu.

Comment: @Zeynel You probably shouldn't make the permissions on anything in `/etc` more permissive.  They're protected for a reason, and generally to edit them you should be using `sudo` or similar.

Comment: Using `sudo` creates exactly the issue he's referring to.

Comment: @GeorgeSpiceland it doesn't have to. Use sudo to run the editor rather than changing ownership so you can edit files as yourself.